# Who to use $or and $in at the same query in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Hi guys I'm facing some problems to use both $or and $in in Meteor.

I follow the book MongoDB The Definitive Guide:

> db.raffle.find({$or : [{ticket_no : {$in : [725, 542, 390]}}, {winner : true}]})

But is not working. Maybe because the miniMongo doesn't accept ?

This is my code:

```
keyArray = Session.get("search_keywords").split(" ");
console.log(keyArray);
keywords = [];
for (var i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
  keywords.push(new RegExp(keyArray[i],"i"));
  console.log(keywords);
}
  console.log(keywords);
  data = Data.find({$or:[{title:{$in: keywords}}, {sort: {SortCreated: -1}}).fetch();
  console.log(sedis)
```

Comment: Have you tried this in the shell?

Comment: I have not tried the code you posted, but it looks like the call to Data.find is badly formed? The value of the $or starts with a [ looks like an array, first element is the title in document, and then the sort document but doesn't seem to end... I'd suggest you build up an example query in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query works fine for me via the `meteor mongo` command line.

However your second query doesn't work because you're passing a list to the `$or` operator, but there's only one thing in the list (and as @Alan Spencer said, the list isn't completed).  Also, you can treat `sort` as a function. Try:

```
Data.find({title:{$in: keywords}}).sort({SortCreated: -1})
```

Add the .fetch() if you want to log the data, leave it out if you're passing to a template.

Comment: Sorry for the lot of typos. But what I mean by that was this: Data.find({$or:[{title:{$in:[/CreatiFriday/i]}}]}).fetch();. Seems that de $in don't accept the RegExp. When I try this return anything. I'm trying to make a better query searching for arrays of RegExp too not only one keyword.